# Is there a hereditary Lindelof space which does not satisfy countable chain condition?

Tags: general-topology, examples-counterexamples

Is there a hereditary Lindelof space which does not satisfy countable chain condition?

Recall that a topological space satisfies the countable chain condition if each disjoint collection of open sets is countable.

Thanks.

Comment: No, in a hereditarily LF space every discrete subset is countable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NO. If $F$ is an uncountable family of pairwise-disjoint non-empty open sets of $X$ then $F$ is an uncountable  open cover of the subspace $\cup F$ with no proper sub-cover. So the subspace $\cup F$ is not Lindelof. So $X$ is not hereditarily Lindelof.